# How to switch to quoted class name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to switch a class out with JavaScript.
From this

```
class=product neutral //background color is grey
```

to this

```
class=product correct //background color is green

if (trueProduct == 12){
        document.getElementById("userAnswer").innerHTML = "class='product correct'";    
        }
```

HTML

```
<span id="userAnswer" class="product neutral"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList), it's the most convenient here.

```
var answer = document.getElementById("userAnswer");
answer.classList.remove("neutral");
answer.classList.add("correct");
```

The `classList` allows you to *toggle* or *add* or *remove* a specific class without altering any others.

Comment: +1, but don't forget to mention that it's only supported in recent browsers.

Comment: "it's only supported in recent IE" FTFY :-) Good catch though, I didn't think IE9 wouldn't grok it. For other browsers I only care for current stable versions since they have auto updaters (like IE finally should if it intends to be useful).

Comment: How do you implement that in the code to switch the class, using classlist?

Comment: @user2374200 `.remove("neutral")` goes from "product neutral" to "product", and the next call `.add("correct")` makes it "product correct". Nothing complicated

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If you want to change the all the class names you can use this,

```
document.getElementById("userAnswer").className = "product correct";
```

If you just want to add another class in, you can use this,

```
document.getElementById("userAnswer").className += " correct";
```

Read about [.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) here

Comment: += adds one in (ah... I didn't think of concatenation that way) That's cool!  Thanks, badZoke

Comment: For concatenation, you should not forget the blank. Or you'd end up with a `neutralcorrect` class.

Comment: updated my answer, please have a look, you just need a space before you concat the next class name

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) (the empty string between `…>` and `</span>` in your case), but the [`className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className):

```
document.getElementById("userAnswer").className = "product correct";
```

Alternatively, you might use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute):

```
document.getElementById("userAnswer").setAttribute("class", "product correct");
```

Answer (score 0):

`element.innerHTML` is the actual content of the element, what you are looking for is:

```
if (trueProduct == 12) {
    document.getElementById("userAnswer").className = "product correct";    
}
```